# log4j.properties configuration issues along with ant configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, log4j

I've spent a lot of time reading the posts on stackoverflow regarding log4j and the different ways it can be implemented. I've decided to take the approach of log4j.properties. I am still running into issues when I run from within eclipse or from ant with:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (My.Class).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I've done two things thus far:

- Created the log4j.properties file in the root of the /src folder
- Moved the log4j.properties file into the package where the .java file exists.

Both instances produce the same issue.  Here is the code I am using in my class:

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(My.class);
```

I have read over and over that the properties file needs to be in the classpath.  I feel like i have done that, but maybe not.  Here is my package structure:

src

- packageA

  - myclass.java
  - log4j.properties (attempt 2)
- packageB
- packageC
- packageD
- log4j.properties (attempt 1)

*Let me point out I'd like every java file in all the packages to use the same log4j.properties. If there is an easier way to configure this other than redundantly coping props files around let me know. I was thinking I'd have to switch to using a resource loader.*

**Moving on to my ant issue:**

I have the exact same issue in ant. I have added what I thought I needed from what I read on apache's site to get ant to run w/o issue, but to no avail.

here is the additional entry in my compile target...

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar">
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target>
<javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeAntRuntime="false"/>
<copy todir="${classes.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${source.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</copy>
</target>
```

I should also note my junit target has the included classpath.

I also attempted adding the -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path to file and I still see the warnings after that... I'm at a loss.

I was under the impression this would copy my .properties file into the classpath of ant.

Answer (score 1):

for ant i added:

```
<path id="properties">
    <dirset dir="${config.dir}"/>
</path>
```

where ${config.dir} is the path to the /src/config folder where the log4j.properties exists.

Still working on getting eclipse to work, it shouldnt be too different with classpaths in eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, to pick up files you need to add the directory to the classpath. Another way to do this is the pathelement statement within the ANT path. On an unrelated issue checkout SLF4J and Logback.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is that my log4j.properties must be in the root of the classpath. 
Since my classpath src includes test code in the applybc2014 package, I've put my log4j.properties there. Note, I'm also excluding ONLY java files.

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="src/ca/bccampus/tests/applybc2014"/>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" classpathref="classpath"/>        
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>            
    </copy>
</target>
```